# Getting an error in using particular "?" this operator,How to use it in swirl?

Tags: r, swirl

I am using swirl package for R programming. And for that,  in a particular part I have to give this command which gives this error and that's why can't progress further.
   ?c

```
Error in shell.exec(url) :

file association for 'https://127.0.0.1:19202/library/base/html/c.html' is not available or invalid
```

Please help me to solve this problem, otherwise I am stuck here and can't get any progress.

Comment: what command/action causes the error?

Comment: "?c" or any help file.

Comment: I mean any help function like?c or?list.files

Comment: oh i see what you're saying. my guess would be it's an issue with how your OS is handling html files rather than an R or swirl-specific issue... not sure what OS you're on, but see if you can find the "Open With" properties for `.html` files and ensure something hasn't messed that up. beyond that, not sure

Comment: which lesson of swirl is?

Comment: @lispHK01 thanks for the help!!  I fixed it by making another search engine my default. Html search engine

Comment: @SabDem R programming,  assignment 1

Comment: cool, glad you got it working!

Answer (score -1):

Type below,It worked for me

```
info()
skip()
```